# Endoscope app USB DEVICE DETACHED when open LED light?

Tags: android, uvc

I've developed an Android App Supports Endoscope using library [UVCCamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera).
Everything working properly but when using the camera with LED Light, a moment later the camera will disconnect and show the message "USB DEVICE DETACHED". This error also cannot find and not show in log console.
When I tested the app with similar apps in the Google Play (CameraFi, UsbWebCamera), I also found the same problem.
Any suggestion about this?

This link is video I recorded. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkXbZo6AO8c
I using Samsung Note 2 and Redmi2 in test.

Thank you.

Comment: My only suggestions is to 1) try other devices, including PC to make sure endoscope is working correctly and 2) add logging to the library as it appears to be completely open-source including the NDK/JNI layer. Good luck.